# Text added after and outside the tikzpicture environment lies on top of the image

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I have added a rectangle using the `tikzpicture` environment. But whatever text is added after and outside the environment lies on top of the image. I've been searching for a solution but haven't come across one. I apologize for any mistakes on my part. Apparently a simple `\vspace` doesn't work either. I am using the `scrartcl` document class. Please help. The code is as follows:

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(5,0)}]
 \draw (0,-4) node[below]{($x_i, y_i$)} -- (4,-4) node[below]{($x_i + dx_i, y_i$)} -- (4,0) node[above]{($x_i+dx_i,y_i+dy_i$)} -- 
(0,0) node[above]{($x_i,y_i+dy_i$)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using `overlay`, if you remove this it will flow with the text not above it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Some text above ... Some text above ... Some text above ... Some text above ... Some text above ... Some text above ... Some text above ...

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,shift={(5,0)}]
 \draw (0,-4) node[below]{($x_i, y_i$)} -- (4,-4) node[below]{($x_i + dx_i, y_i$)} -- (4,0) node[above]{($x_i+dx_i,y_i+dy_i$)} -- (0,0) node[above] {($x_i,y_i+dy_i$)} -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

And some text below ... And some text below ... And some text below ... And some text below ... And some text below ... And some text below ... And some text below ... And some text below ... 

\end{document}
```

[image]